# Numba and llvmlite won't install on sage cygwin

Tags: python, sage

Even under admin on SageMath 9.1 Shell I'm unable to install numba
(buildchain is probably broken, is there a workaround -- `conda install`?).
Numba would help reshape matrices and stuff.

So here's basically an error:

```
$ sage --pip install numba

Collecting numba
  Using cached files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/81/6fd1dd064bcf71a79da109e8966a39e2da61d68bf0bd1e0839fa997f8c41/numba-0.51.2.tar.gz
Collecting llvmlite<0.35,>=0.34.0.dev0 (from numba)
  Using cached files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0b/96/07bfa93a103fb9e3e9ae7f9f7c6687ae714aee66b6f3000da3fad71e0aa2/llvmlite-0.34.0.
<......>
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ju72yen0/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 191, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ju72yen0/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 187, in main
        raise RuntimeError("unsupported platform: %r" % (sys.platform,))
    RuntimeError: unsupported platform: 'cygwin'
    error: command '/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/bin/python3.exe' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
**Command "/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/bin/python3.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-ju72yen0/llvmlite/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-oiztj3wr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ju72yen0/llvmlite/**
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please try do not use image of code, and try write this in the post with the correct format. Text is forever, images... no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is fairly clear: llvmlite, which is a dependency of numba, does not support Cygwin.

It appears that in the llvmlite build script there is [an explicit check](https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/blob/40e27198bf3b9368abeb7640e699a669e2cbee99/ffi/build.py#L177) of supported platforms, which does not currently include cygwin.  There is, however, a somewhat recent [pull request](https://github.com/numba/llvmlite/pull/589) to add cygwin support, but it has not been reviewed yet.

P.S. conda does not support cygwin

Comment: So, does it make any difference if it is sage shell -- I install it sage --pip install numba, not conda install?

Comment: Sage for Windows doesn't use or include conda since conda does ship cygwin-based packages.